# Onenote multiple instances?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

Is it possible to run multiple instances of OneNote (any edition)? I.e. run two separate instances on same machine, but they both use either different user accounts or opened up different sets of separate notebooks. I know you can open multiple notebooks, but I don't want to be scrolling too much because I have too many opened notebooks, so I would much rather have separate instances of Onenote each for a separate notebook. Is it possible?

Comment: For new window (and not necessarily a new instance) you can use the [OneNote command line shortcut](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-in-Microsoft-Office-OneNote-2007-29468957-1fcc-48b8-8821-00fe5518493a#tblID0ECBBAAA) `/sidenote`

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to open multiple instances of OneNote 2013, and each one can have a different notebook open as its "focused" notebook, but all the "pinned" and "recently opened" notebooks will be the same.

In OneNote 2013 with Windows 8.1, if you have one instance of OneNote open, you can right-click the icon on the taskbar and select "Microsoft OneNote" from the menu. A second OneNote window will open up. You can then browse to a separate notebook.

You can also use the "View" ribbon and choose "New Window" and browse to a separate notebook. The "New Docked Window" opens up an always-on-top version of OneNote pinned to the side of your screen for notetaking.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have *10+ OneNote windows open* (to multitask between notes, plans, meeting minutes, pictures...). From what you described I think what you need is **multiple windows** (not necessarily multiple instances - consider each OneNote window something like a Chrome tab).

To do this there are different ways:

1. **Quickest**: pin OneNote icon to the taskbar in a certain position (e.g. the 5th counted from the left). Then you can press Win+Shift+5 shortcut key to launch a new OneNote window (same for any pinned application). Then you can also press Win+5 to switch between them
2. Press Win+R to open "Run" dialog and enter "onenote" (you can also try "excel", "winword", "powerpnt", "notepad", "mspaint"...)
3. If you are familiar with command line tool, type "onenote" or "start onenote"

Once the window is open, you can open one/multiple notebook(s) in it. The notebook can come from the same Microsoft account or different accounts.

All solutions above work for Windows 7 and 10.